# No EC2 Key pair listed trying to create new EB instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Apologies if this should have an obvious answer.  Nothing seems to google the solution.

We have been using south-east region. We are trying to create (using console) a new Elastic Beanstalk in Oregon (USA West 2) region.

When we get to select key pair there are none listed. (Creating in southeast region always listed without issue)

We have 2 IAM users created. The keys are listed when we create other regions.

But when we try and select region to configure new users/groups it says these are configured globally.

What are we missing?

thanks
Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keypairs are per region and cannot be shared across regions.

[Creating Your Key Pair Using Amazon EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html)

> Some Amazon EC2 resources can be shared between regions, but key pairs
>   can't. For example, if you create a key pair in the US West (Oregon)
>   region, you can't see or use the key pair in another region.

Solution: Add/Import the key(s) in your new region.

Comment: thanks helloV - thanks for the lead, i see now that you have to add keys to the EC2 services, before you can use on EB. not as intuitive as it should be but hey.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Resource Locations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/resources.html), I think Key pairs are global or regional.

> You can use the key pairs that you create using Amazon EC2    only in the region where you created them. **You can create and upload an RSA key pair that you can use in all regions.**